# Implemeting CustomRoleProvider and use the role for the authorisation in MVC3 asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, roleprovider

I've been learning how to implement CustomRoleProvider from a few tutorials and managed to implement 2 main methods as below

```
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string userName)
    {
        string connectionString =
          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDb"].ConnectionString;
        DataContext context = new DataContext(connectionString);
        Table<UserObj> usersTable = context.GetTable<UserObj>();
        UserObj userObj = usersTable.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
        string roleId = userObj.UserRoleID;

        if (roleId != null)
            return roleId.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
        else
            return new string[] { }; 

    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string userName, string roleName)
    {
        string connectionString =
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDb"].ConnectionString;
        DataContext context = new DataContext(connectionString);
        Table<UserObj> usersTable = context.GetTable<UserObj>();
        UserObj userObj = usersTable.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);

        if (userObj != null)
        {
            string roleId = userObj.UserRoleID;
            if (roleId.Equals(roleName))
                return true;
        }
       return false;
    }
```

Then I added [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] on the index method of a controller which I want only admin to get access. When I tried to access the page, it seems to perform a restriction ok, for example, if I entered url:

```
       http://localhost:60353/module
```

..it redirected me to

```
        http://localhost:60353/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fmodule
```

However, the role didn't seem to be checked.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I also face same problem but i am able to call CustomProvider Method:

> IsUserInRoles()

explicitly,but it does seem to be correct because the accessibility is not changed....it always redirect to login screen only.......